# Array accessing in arduino and for loop

Tags: arduino-uno

How can I access data values from the arrays in Arduino programming?

The program is given below :

```
 int myArraylt[24]=    {3530,1580,3880,2780,4040,11260,7935,6655,2100,5100,1450,2200,2200,5900,6180,4230,2405,3560,4535,12635,12085,3500,930,3430};
 int myArraygt[24]=    {0,0,0,0,0,0,6320,5496.9,5948,4124.1,3848.4,3573,3022.2,3297.6,3298.2,3573,4123.2,0,0,0,0,0,0};

 void setup() {

 for (int i=1;i=1;i++)
   if (myArraygt(i)>myArraylt(i))
   println( SSystem is on MG);
   else
   println( SSystem is on GRID); 
 }

 void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there are few mistakes

1. array index starts from `0` ,but in your for loop you started it from `1`
2. In the loop condition expression is checked as `i=1` it runs loop only for  array index `1`
3. In order to access data values from array use `array[i]` format(not array(i))
4. for printing in arduino use `Serial.println()` ,not just println()

For accessing the array values the code should be as follows

```
    int myArraylt[24]=      {3530,1580,3880,2780,4040,11260,7935,6655,2100,5100,1450,2200,2200,5900,6180,4230,2405,3560,4535,12635,12085,3500,930,3430};
     int myArraygt[24]=    {0,0,0,0,0,0,6320,5496.9,5948,4124.1,3848.4,3573,3022.2,3297.6,3298.2,3573,4123.2,0,0,0,0,0,0};

     void setup() {

     for (int i=0;i<24;i++)
       if (myArraygt[i]>myArraylt[i])
           Serial.println( SSystem is on MG); 
       else
           Serial.println( SSystem is on GRID);
     }

     void loop() {
     // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
     }
```

And if you want to print SSystem is on MG and SSystem is on GRID on the screen then it must be put inside double quotes as `Serial.println( "SSystem is on MG");` and `Serial.println( "SSystem is on GRID");`

Comment: I think you want to print `SSystem is on MG` and `SSystem is on GRID` . You havnt mention it in question if you want to do it then it must be put inside double quotes as `Serial.println( "SSystem is on MG");` and `Serial.println( "SSystem is on GRID"); `. Mark it accepted and upvote if answer is useful

Comment: upto this time a have worked on Matalb, and now i am moving toward hardware interfacing. it is really helpful for me.

Comment: please tell me how can i accept and upvote on this site?

Comment: Thanks for cooperation.